# Create single animation from programme

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

This programme fills a figure with square patches. The y axis limit is set so that it will be seen that there is only one patch in one position. It plots this filling process. I want to record the filling as an animation and am trying to do so with 'matplotlib.animation'. I turn the plotting part of the programme into a function (def filler(b):) so that I can pass this function to the animation lines at the bottom. When I run the programme I get an error right at the end of the plotting saying Python has stopped working. Please could somebody explain why. Thanks.

Note that I don't know what the b in the function argument is meant to represent. I include it because without it the programme doesn't run, asking for a positional argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

startx = 0
endx = 10
blocks = 100
points = np.random.randint(startx,endx,size=blocks)
y = [-1]*int(endx-startx)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
ax.set_xlim(startx,endx)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)

def filler(b):

    for i in range(blocks):
        z = 5
        a = patches.Rectangle((points[i],z),1,1,ec='k',fc=(1-i/blocks,i/(2*blocks),i/blocks))
        ax.add_patch(a)  
        while z>y[int(points[i])]+1:
            z=z-1
            plt.pause(0.001)
            a.set_y(z)
        y[int(points[i])]=z

filler_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, filler,interval=50, repeat=False, blit=True)
filler_ani.save('filler.mp4')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question mixes two different types of animations. Using a loop and  `plt.draw()`, and a `FuncAnimation`. This will lead to chaos, as essentially the complete animation on screen is done during the first frame of the `FuncAnimation`, at the end of that first frame the animation fails.

So, one has to decide. Since it seems you want to do a `FuncAnimation` here,  in order to be able to save it, one needs to get rid of the `plt.draw`. Then the problem is that there is a for loop and a while loop. This makes it hard to use a framenumber based animation.
Instead one may use a generator based animation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

startx = 0
endx = 10
blocks = 101
points = np.random.randint(startx,endx,size=blocks)
y = [-1]*int(endx-startx)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
ax.set_xlim(startx,endx)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)

def filler():
    yield None
    for i in range(blocks):
        z = 5
        a = patches.Rectangle((points[i],z),1,1,ec='k',fc="r")
        ax.add_patch(a) 
        while z>y[int(points[i])]+1:
            z=z-1
            a.set_y(z)
            yield a
        y[int(points[i])]=z

filler_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, lambda x: None, frames=filler, 
                                     interval=50, blit=False, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

This is kind of hacky, but stays most closely to your initial code.